# PHP Command line output and Browser/Curl are different

Tags: php, shell, output

my script is designed as below-

**server list is placed in -servers.txt.**

```
servera01
servera02
servera03
serverb01
serverb02
serverb03
```

**my shell script is -status_check1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat servers.txt`; do
   ssh -q  sv-p-jb@$i ls -l /apps/jboss/welcome-content/keepAlive.html > /dev/null
 #server="$i"
 if [ $? == 0 ]; then

     echo -e "Server $i is in VIP  | \n"
 else
     echo -e "Server $i is not in VIP | \n"
 fi

done
```

**my php script is -test.php**

```
<?php
exec('./status_check1.sh', $output);
#echo implode("\n", $output);
$myarray = explode('|', implode($output));
$arr_length = count($myarray);
for($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++)
{
echo $myarray["$i"];
echo "<br />";
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

i am getting php command line (php test.php) output as -

```
servera01 is in VIP  |
servera02 is in VIP  |
servera03 is in VIP  |
serverb01 is in VIP  |
serverb02 is in VIP  |
serverb03 is in VIP  |
```

But when i access it on browser, getting below output.

```
servera01 is not in VIP  
servera02 is not in VIP  
servera03 is not in VIP  
serverb01 is in VIP  
serverb02 is in VIP  
serverb03 is in VIP
```

Could you please advise why this different output comes in browser.
I am not able to understand, how the same shell script is returning 'not' in browser.

Thanks.

Comment: why is there one space more after the serverb0x before the "is" both in php and shell output? Might this be part of a problem? Do you authenticate using a private ssh key into an ssh-agent or similar or how?

Comment: Did you mean `Server servera01 is (not) in VIP |`? I think @StefanHegny is on the right path. The Apache user (or similar) might not have saved any ssh-agent permissions.

Comment: Try `sudo -u www-data php test.php` if you use Apache.

Comment: Space is not an issue, I have fixed it above.

Comment: Also i have tried above command the output is -
sudo: unknown user: www-data
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
Could you please advise.

Comment: I agree with @Quasimodo'sclone suggestion. Bash scripts are always causing me similar problems. It's because there are variables ( in this case, permissions ) that are outside of program control.